# Displaying prices

Tags: python, django, currency

I'm getting prices in different currencies and want to display Brazilian R$
My formatting doesn't work and the display looks like this:

Price: 1.15..000.,00 R$

For good flexibility I've stored the price as a string: `price=db.StringProperty(verbose_name="price")`

I tried to implement my own filter and it didn't work:
`{{ ad.price|separate }}&nbsp;R$`

```
def separate(n, sep='.'):
    ln = list(str(n))
    ln.reverse()
    newn = []
    while len(ln) > 3:
        newn.extend(ln[:3])
        newn.append(sep)
        ln = ln[3:]
    newn.extend(ln)
    newn.reverse()
    return "".join(newn)
```

Can you help me? Should I just remove the filter? Should I enforce some regex to the input instead? A link to my site is http://www.koolbusiness.com/servead/4252196

UPDATE: I'm considering using something like one of these filters:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

def currency(value): # doesn't work
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
    return locale.currency(value, grouping=True)

register.filter(currency)


def currencyWithoutUsingLocale(value): # needs adjustment
    value=float(value)
    symbol = '$' 
    thousand_sep = ''
    decimal_sep = ''
    # try to use settings if set 
    try:
        symbol = settings.CURRENCY_SYMBOL
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    try:
        thousand_sep = settings.THOUSAND_SEPARATOR
        decimal_sep = settings.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR
    except AttributeError:
        thousand_sep = ',' 
        decimal_sep = '.' 

    intstr = str(int(value))
    f = lambda x, n, acc=[]: f(x[:-n], n, [(x[-n:])]+acc) if x else acc
    intpart = thousand_sep.join(f(intstr, 3))
    return "%s%s%s%s" % (symbol, intpart, decimal_sep, ("%0.2f" % value)[-2:])

register.filter(currencyWithoutUsingLocale)
```

Comment: "Didn't work" is not very helpful. What happened when you tried?

Comment: Selling per ounce lists as a String and there could be other combinations I should admit. I fail to think up a regex or rule that doesn't make it impossible for someone to sell e.g. metal per ounce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storing the price as a string is the first problem. It should be a Decimal. If you look at the Python standard library documentation for Decimal, you will see this http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#recipes

That moneyfmt recipe should do what you want

Comment: Thanks! You're right that I probably should choose a number datatype for storing prices but the disadvantage with that is that it won't allow "prices" with words such as "10 per ounce" or "A combinar" or "Negotiable" which I suppose is a drawback I can take. Maybe I can try cast the value to a number and if casting works then I use the moneyfmt and that way I can still allow listing prices I didn't think of.

Comment: Make a class with price, quantity and units. Many prices will be like 1234.56,1,por but some will be 10,1,onça. For the really strange ones you can either use negative numbers or .01. For instance .01,1,combi would mean "A combinar" and .01,1,neg. You define all the units that you need and do special handling based on units.

Answer (score 2):

Currency formatting is a feature of [locale](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html).

http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.currency

Comment: Thank you. I do save which currency it is directly so that an article from Brazil could get listed in US dollars if they want. So i suppose all this depends on how flexible I want my implementation to be.

Comment: @Niklas R: "all this depends on how flexible I want my implementation to be".  No.  Locale is always for formatting currency whether your application is very flexible or inflexible.  Locale is always how currency is formatted.

Comment: I understand. To me Locale was for instance EN for english while currency is something like USD. I just didn't want to rule out that even though "locale" is `pt` or `pt-br` or `pt_br` for Brazil, that doesn't rule out that users in Brazil, on a Brazilian website, in brazilian portugues still could post an articles priced in `USD`. If I don't require that flexibility I could just set currency the same as country. If I know longitude and latitude I still might not know which currency since that could be totally up to the user if I allow other currencies than the country's own.

Comment: locale only works when users log into the UNIX machine and have the locale set correctly. That might be true in a business environment for command line apps, but is not true for web applications where no UNIX login takes place.

Comment: @Niklas R: Correct.  Locale doesn't rule anything out.

Comment: @MichaelDillon: you can use Locale in Windows environment too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzz3tw78

Answer (score 2):

You can use `locale._override_localeconv` dict to set your own overwrites:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')
>>> locale.currency(1234.56)
'1234,56 R$'
>>> locale._override_localeconv.update({'p_cs_precedes': 1, 'n_cs_precedes': 1})
>>> locale.currency(1234.56)
'R$ 1234,56'
```

You can use this `locale._override_localeconv.update({'p_cs_precedes': 1, 'n_cs_precedes': 1})` line right after the `import locale`, if you want.

Comment: btw, remember to use Decimal to store money, not Text, ok?